# Errors when using VOSK for real-time speech recognition (python)

Tags: python

I am trying to install the VOSK library for speech recognition, I also installed a trained model and unpacked it in .../vosk/vosk-model-ru-0.42.. But I have errors during the launch of the model, I don't understand what it wants from me[image]

I didn't find a solution in google

Comment: None of that output is "error" information - it is showing what I would expect. Are there actual error messages?